# android: share an url to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I need to share the next url to facebook:

> *https://example.com/fb/?hash={"name":"Name","language":"en"}*

I use the next code:

```
Intent i = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
                                                    .setType("text/plain")
                                                    .setText(url)
                                                    .getIntent()
                                                    .setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                                            startActivity(i);
```

But on my facebook wall I can see only the first part of my sent url(url without params):

> https://example.com/fb/?hash

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was resolved using URLEncoder for params:

```
shareUrl = rootUrl + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
```